# z-index iframe InternetExplorer vs Chrome,Fox,

Tags: css, iframe, z-index

img { z-index:1;}
iframe { z-index:99;}

```
<iframe name="frameid" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="100" width="100" marginheight="0")></iframe><img src="img.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
```

Chrome,Fox,Safari would show img.jpg just fine 
(iframe at z-index99 is empty so lets show image below )

IE 7 shows nothing at all 
(iframe is empty so lets paint it white or something)
Is there any way to teach IE 7,* to display nothing at all if nothing at iframe
I looked at Using IFRAME Elements at msdn but...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is related to the Z-Index, when I remove it AND add "allowtransparency="true"" to the iframe, it works as intended, check out this snippet:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>simple document</title>
        <style>
            img { background:red; display:block; position:absolute; top:2px; left:2px; }
            iframe { border:2px solid blue; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; background:transparent; display:block; zoom:1}
            body{background:pink}
            div {position:relative;}
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe name="frameid" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="100" width="100" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        <img src="img.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>`

Weird, it seems that SO it's breaking the layout of the code, but copy and paste that into a .html file and you can see that the image is being shown as below the iframe, another option would be to set the image as the background-image for the

Good luck!